# Code is executed twice without calling

Tags: c#

I have a few instructions inside a "button_click" event and I can summarize
them like this:

1. Check if an image's path exists
2. Call a function to determine if the image is grayscale
3. Instantiate another form and show it with "ShowDialog" method
4. When the user closes that form, I execute some code to insert information into a database
5. Dispose the new form

The weird thing is that the step 2 is executed again once the method asociated with the "button_click" has ended. I put some "Console.Writeline()" to know the exact time that steps are execute and [this is the result](http://pastebin.com/Q7V7C6XU)

Lines 8 and 9 were showed again in lines 23,23 which means that the "IsGrayScale" was executed again (and that throws an exception). This only happens on Windows 7 and I can't do a remote debug due to an external library which is critical for this software so I can't remove it. I know that a Try-Catch can help but I want to know: why is this happening?.

Code:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImagenCortadaRuta))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Por favor corte la imagen.", "Procesador OCR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    return;
}

if (!File.Exists(ImagenCortadaRuta))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No existe el archivo " + ImagenCortadaRuta + ".\nCorte la imagen nuevamente.", "Procesador OCR", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return;
}

var intType = 0;
if (rdbPrensa.Checked) intType = 1;
if (rdbRevista.Checked) intType = 2;

var frmRegNoti = new frmProcRegNoticia();
frmRegNoti.blLanzadoDesdeOcr = true;
frmRegNoti.adminDetailProd1.PermitirIngreso = false;
foreach (DataGridViewRow item in dgvPeriodistas.Rows)
{
    _lstintPeriodistas.Add(item.Cells["prd_id"].Value.ToString());
}

Console.WriteLine($"IsGrayScale [ImagenCortadaRuta]: {ImagenCortadaRuta} : {DateTime.Now}");
Console.WriteLine($"ImagenMiniatura {ImagenMiniatura} : {DateTime.Now}");
var imgTemp = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(ImagenCortadaRuta);
var blColor = Utility.IsGrayScale(imgTemp);
imgTemp.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine($" ================================== Fin IsGrayScale : {DateTime.Now}");
Console.WriteLine($" ================================== INI ImportarDatos : {DateTime.Now}");
frmRegNoti.ImportarDatos(elementosFinal, dtpFecha.Value, intType, txtMedio._ID.ToString(), txtSeccion._ID.ToString(), txtMSecc._ID.ToString(), txtPag.Text, ImagenCortadaRuta, dicTranscripcion.txtControlTexto.InnerText, txtResumen.Text, dicTitular.txtControlTexto.InnerText, TamañoVertical, CantidadColumnas, CantidadPaginas, ImagenMiniatura, "", blColor, _lstintPeriodistas, IdAnalisis);
frmRegNoti.ShowDialog();
Console.WriteLine($" ================================== Fin ShowDialog : {DateTime.Now}");
if (frmRegNoti.GuardadoCorrecto)
{
    Console.WriteLine($" ================================== DENTRO frmRegNoti.GuardadoCorrecto: {DateTime.Now}");
    //Una vez cerrado actualizamos los bloques
    _existeBloqueTemporal = ProcesadorOCRMetodos.MarcarComoProcesada(IdGrupoActual, CantidadPaginas, InformacionBloque.ConvertirATexto(_totalCoordenadasActuales), out _strError);
    _notaGuardada = true;
    Console.WriteLine($" ================================== FIN MarcarComoProcesada: {DateTime.Now}");
    Console.WriteLine($" ================================== INI BorrarForm: {DateTime.Now}");
    BorrarForm();
    for (var indicePagina = 0; indicePagina < FrDocumentAccess.FRDocumentPagesCount; indicePagina++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" ================================== INI ActivarFRDocument: {DateTime.Now}");
        FrDocumentAccess.ActivarFRDocument(FrDocumentAccess.FRDocumentPages[indicePagina].FRDocumentIndex);
        Console.WriteLine($" ================================== INI CargarInformacionBloques: {DateTime.Now}");
        CargarInformacionBloques(FrDocumentAccess.FRDocumentPages[indicePagina].IdPagina);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($" ================================== FIN BorrarForm: {DateTime.Now}");
}
else
{
    ProcesadorOCRMetodos.EliminarAnalisisDeGrupo(IdGrupoActual, out _strError);
}
Console.WriteLine($" ================================== INI frmRegNoti.Dispose : {DateTime.Now}");
frmRegNoti.Dispose();
Console.WriteLine($" ================================== FIN frmRegNoti.Dispose : {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Comment: Most likely, something else is calling `Utility.IsGrayScale`. Right click on `IsGrayScale` in the source and select "Find All References" from the context menu.

Comment: I did it and it has only one reference.

Comment: Could something else be calling `btnSave_Click`?

Comment: Once reference again. This method even has a "File.Exists(ImagenCortadaRuta)" in order to prevent "Utility.IsGrayScale" causes an exception so calling "btnSave_Click" again will not affect anything

Comment: How do you register the btnSave_Click event? I'm thinking you are registering the event twice

Comment: I'd stick a breakpoint in `btnSave_Click`, hit F10 the first time you hit the breakpoint. I'm guessing you may hit the same breakpoint again after the child window closes -- then you can look at the call stack and see who the culprit is.

Comment: It is hard to pinpoint the source of this with the context we have now. Since `IsGrayScale` throw an exception on 2nd invocation, you can log this exception, specifically its StackTrace, and analyze from there.

Comment: I will try logging the whole stacktrace, but there's no way that "btnSave_Click" is being called twice due to validations. The code and log messages (Console.Writeline) does not match the second time so the method "btnSave_Click" is not being executed twice, only part of it.